# Format an NSNumber in to superscript or subscript unicode characters

Tags: unicode, nsstring, string-formatting, nsnumber

Unicode includes superscript characters such as "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹" and also subscript: "₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉". I would like to format a number in to either super or subscript numbers – I believe it should then be fine to use in a `UILabel` or `UITextField`.

Specifically, I don't want to use an `NSAttributedString`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a category on NSString, **but read the huge caveat** that follows before using.

```
-(NSString*) asSuperscript
{
    return [self tranformWithMap:
            @{
              @"0": @"⁰",
              @"1": @"¹",
              @"2": @"²",
              @"3": @"³",
              @"4": @"⁴",
              @"5": @"⁵",
              @"6": @"⁶",
              @"7": @"⁷",
              @"8": @"⁸",
              @"9": @"⁹"
              }];
}

-(NSString*) tranformWithMap: (NSDictionary *) map
{
    NSString *output = self;

    for (NSString *from in map.allKeys)
    {
        output = [output stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: from withString: map[from]];
    }

    return output;
}
```

The implementation above is amazingly inefficient, but will do for short strings – and hey, computers are quick, right?

**However, on iOS**, where I need this, the system font's superscript characters look terrible. In particular the **characters for "123" don't vertically line up** with "0456789", which are all higher up!